# Reverse Array не могу вывести с цикла

Tags: java, массивы, reverse

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]public class ReverseArray {

```
public static String[] reverse(String[] strings) {
    //TODO: Напишите код, который меняет порядок расположения элементов внутри массива на обратный.
    for (int i = strings.length-1;i>=0;i-- ) {
       System.out.print(strings[i]);
    }
    return strings;
}
```

//застрял на элементарном функция разворачивает массив но как вывести результат из цикла?

Comment: Правильно говорить "**из** цикла". Что такое "вывести её с цикла на return"? Кого "её"? И что значит "на return"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строго говоря, если просто меняется порядок элементов во входном массиве, метод `reverse` не обязан возвращать тот же самый массив и потому может иметь тип `void` (как и `Arrays.sort`).

Для перестановки элементов нужно просто пройти входной массив до середины, переставляя первый и последний элементы:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public static <T> void reverse1(T[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length, m = n-- / 2; i < m; i++) {
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n - i];
        arr[n - i] = tmp;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")    
public static <T> T[] reverse(T ... arr) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length, m = n-- / 2; i < m; i++) {
        T tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n - i];
        arr[n - i] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Для массивов примитивных типов `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]`, и т.д. потребуется написать отдельные перегруженные методы:

```java
public static int[]  reverse(int ... arr)  {...}
public static long[] reverse(long ... arr) {...}
// etc.
```

---

Пример для конкретного массива `String[]`:

```java
public static String[] reverse(String ... arr) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length, m = n-- / 2; i < m; i++) {
        String tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n - i];
        arr[n - i] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: я еще до таких сложных конфигураций не дошел. Нам нужно условно сделать всё на элементарных началах массивов!(

Comment: Привел пример для `String[]`, правда, не совсем понял, с чем именно возникла проблема

Comment: m=n--/2 не совсем понял для чего?

Comment: насколько я понял тот цикл который я указал в начале не заработает без такого рода перестановок? или он вообще не в кассу?

Comment: 1. Цикл в вопросе просто _печатает_ содержимое массива в обратном порядке, не меняя его содержимое. 2. `m` - середина массива с использованием пост-декремента для `n`, чтобы не вычитать каждый раз 1 при обращении к последнему элементу, например, для 4 элементов `m = 2, n = 3`: [0] ⇔ [3], [1] ⇔ [2]; для 5, `m = 2, n = 4`: [0] ⇔ [4], [1] ⇔ [3]

Comment: Да все сработало как по часам) Спасибо. Такой шаблон функций всегда используется в случае реверса?

Comment: Не всегда, но достаточно часто.  Может, например, меняться направление итерации (декремент от середины к началу, см. [AbstractBuilder::reverse](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#l1385)), ещё одна вариация -- вынести отдельно функцию `swap`, как реализовано в [`Collections::reverse(List<?> list)`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l434)

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```
String[] newStringArr = new String[str.length];

for (int i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   newStringArr[str.length - 1 - i] = str[i];
}

return newStringArr;
```

Comment: Не думаю: "который меняет порядок расположения элементов внутри массива".

Comment: @Igor да что-то не так прочитал....думал там строка по символам......теперь массив

Comment: я про в подаче инфы)

Comment: пишет ошибку( сейчас кину сканы...

Comment: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Необходимо изменить порядок в переданном массиве, и вернуть его же. Меняйте местами элементы в переданном массиве. ==> expected: [Ljava.lang.String;@1725dc0f<[a, b]> but was: [Ljava.lang.String;@41e36e46<[a, b]>
Expected :[Ljava.lang.String;@1725dc0f
Actual   :[Ljava.lang.String;@41e36e46